# I want my form to progress when you hit the enter key

Tags: javascript, html, forms, enter

my [website](http://www.walshx.com) uses a password to progress.

however i would like the form to work when hitting the enter key

as it is much easier than moving the mouse

here is the current code for the form:

```
<form name="login" style="margin: 0px">
    <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="pass" size="17" onKeyDown="if(event.keyCode==13) event.keyCode=9;" style="width: 152px; margin: 5px;"><br >
    <input type="button" value="Enter" style="width : 150px; margin: 3px" onClick="TheLogin(this.form)" >
</form>
```

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: change input type="button" to "submit", focus it. Enter keypress will submit form.

Comment: off the topic but. are you actually sending the password as $_GET param ??

Comment: The password is not very hidden, found in about 5 seconds... (Pointed out for security reasons)

Answer (score 3):

Add `input type="submit"` instead of `button`. Later use `onsubmit` event to catch it.

Answer (score 3):

No javascript is required for that just set the submit button to type submit.

```
 <input type="submit" value="enter"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

The default action for enter pressed in a form is to invoke the first submit button, so you just need

`<input type="submit" value="enter"/>`

Answer (score 1):

You can either use an input type of "Submit" and that will capture that event. Or, you can do something like this:

```
$('body').keydown(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        alert('Enter key pressed');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**IMPORTANT UPDATE**

DONT use javascript as a medium to verify password and DONT DONT DONT include your password inside your html in a `<script>` tag!

Password verification should ONLY be done server-side!

1. Use `POST` [method](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) in your form and not `GET`
2. Inputs that are used for password should have [type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) set to
   password and not text.
3. Javascript is not needed for default form submit (works with enter).
4. Change your html into this:

> ```
> <form name="login" style="margin: 0px;" method="post">
>     <input type="password" name="pass" size="17" style="width:152px;margin:5px;">
>     <br >
>     <input type="submit" value="Enter" style="width:150px;margin:3px;">
> </form>
> ```